# Who is this female soldier?

Tags: character-identification, magic-the-gathering

The March of the Machine prerelease kit flyer depicts several famous but one unknown humanoid. I can't find her on any Battle card in Gatherer. Who is she?

[image: Unknown female soldier.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching for the black rose symbol and keeping her rings in mind, it's ***Marchesa, Resolute Monarch*** of [Fiora](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=607148):

[image: Marchesa, Resolute Monarch]